Girl gives female soldier a drawing and killed by enemy fire
I saw this one scene when I was a preteen and I haven't been able to figure out what movie it was. It was a modern war movie that couldn't have come out after 2005. There was a female soldier and she had bonded with a little girl in whatever country they were in. The soldiers were evacuating the area (I think via helicopter) and the little girl runs out of her home to give the female soldier a drawing she made her. As the little girl runs back to her home, she is killed by enemies shooting at the soldiers. I'm pretty sure that scene was towards the very end of the movie. The female soldier was pretty torn up about the little girl and one of the other soldiers was consoling her in the helicopter. Please help!!! I've been trying to figure this out for several years!!!

I believe you might be remembering a 2001 episode of the tv series "JAG" entitled Guilt. The character of Mac (Sarah MacKenzie) leads a group of Marines and diplomats to safety from a consolate with the help of a little girl who dies in the way you describe. From an online synopsis:

The “motor-mouth” daughter of a consulate cook, Lylyana, took to [Mac] and drew her a picture. Mac gave her an insignia from her uniform in return. The evacuating helicopter couldn’t land due to small arms fire from the mob. Lylyana led them all through a “secret” tunnel beneath the consulate (that no one knew about) onto the next street, and into her school building. The mob eventually came to the school, as they all were boarding the helicopter, and lobbed mortars. Unbelievably, the girl stood in the courtyard jumping up and down waving that [Mac] had forgotten to take her picture! A mortar was shown exploding directly in front of her as the helicopter took off.


Oh my gosh! That was exactly it!! Thank you SO much! You are awesome!!!!

How do I do that?

@Melissa: Just click the check mark to the left of the question (near the up and down buttons).
